# PowerShell datetime parsing issue

Tags: powershell

I am trying to calculate the expiry of a cert. Providing an array of domain names should give me the list of expiry dates

Getting error related to datetime parsing

```
  Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

Below is the script code

```
$minCertAge = 80
$timeoutMs = 10000
$sites = @(
"hbc.com/namespace/health",
"abcxs.com/namespace/health",
"abcads.com/namespace/health"
)
# Disable certificate validation
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
foreach ($site in $sites)
{
Write-Host Check $site -f Green
$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($site)
$req.Timeout = $timeoutMs
try {$req.GetResponse() |Out-Null} catch {Write-Host URL check error $site`: $_ -f Red}
$expDate = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()

**Write-Host $expDate
Write-Host "above expdate return in format   11/17/2024"**
write-host "---------------------------------"
$certExpDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($expDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
write-host "Errors out with the above line"


[int]$certExpiresIn = ($certExpDate - $(get-date)).Days
$certName = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetName()
$certThumbprint = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetCertHashString()
$certEffectiveDate = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()
$certIssuer = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetIssuerName()
if ($certExpiresIn -gt $minCertAge)
{Write-Host The $site certificate expires in $certExpiresIn days [$certExpDate] -f Green}
else
{
$message= "The $site certificate expires in $certExpiresIn days"
$messagetitle= "Renew certificate"
Write-Host $message [$certExpDate]. Details:`n`nCert name: $certName`Cert thumbprint: $certThumbprint`nCert effective date: $certEffectiveDate`nCert issuer: $certIssuer -f Red
}
write-host "________________" `n
}
```

Comment: So what is in `$expDate` when it fails? (Try to create an [mcve]). You set a timeout on `$req`, it is unlikely that it contains anything if that happens. You might want to [`Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) to capture other issues in your script.

Comment: sample expirydate Write-Host "above expdate return in format   11/17/2024"**

Comment: Note the return value from ```GetExpirationDateString``` is culture-specific and can vary from machine to machine so you can't rely on a hardcoded datetime pattern for ```ParseExact``` working *everywhere*. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getexpirationdatestring?view=net-7.0 - "The GetExpirationDateString method returns a string that shows the date formatted in **Short Date Pattern** followed by the time formatted in **Long Time Pattern**. The date and time are formatted using the current culture and time zone."

Comment: Why do you need to parse a DateTime object?  You just need to compare the current DataTime object against the Expiration DateTime Object.  There is not need to convert to a string.